# For Delphi IDE, Functions list in code editor like in Visual Studio

Tags: delphi, ide, code-editor

For Delphi IDE, Is there any tool/expert to know the name of the function where the cursor is, without scrolling the code editor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[CnPack](http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en) offer that too for free ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Castalia is the tool you want, for all IDE's including the post-Delphi 7 versions.
[Castalia at TwoDesk](http://www.twodesk.com/castalia/)

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, it works nicely for Delphi personality. Do you know such a tool for C++Builder personality of post-Delphi 7 versions?

Answer (score 4):

The Structure Pane provides this information when a code window is open.

Comment: I move cursor up and down, from one procedure to another on the code window, but nothing changes on the Structure Pane. I don't need to look at the list of procedures and move to selected, I want to know the name of the current procedure.

Answer (score 3):

Funny, nobody mentioned GExperts - that's a free addon for Delphi, works flawlessly with all editions from Personal to Architect. And has **a lot** useful stuff in it. Personally I don't even touch Delphi if there's no GExperts installed - but that's me :D

Comment: I use GExperts, but It doesn't provide such a functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I never used it personally, but [CodeRush for Delphi](http://www.qbssoftware.com/product_info.aspx?current=DETAILEDINFO&product=CODER#delphi) might be the tool you are looking for (on the linked page search for "breadcrumb").

Comment: CodeRush is only available up to Delphi 7.